# Pass by list vs pass by reference?

Tags: python

```
def foo(var):
    var = []
    var.append("hello")
    var.append("world")

list = ["bah"]
foo(list)
print(list)
```

is ["bah"] output because python passes the list by value so changes to the list in the function are made to a separate list than the one that is passed in?

or

is ["bah"] output because python passes the list by reference but a new reference is created by the first line in the function so subsequent changes are made to a separate list than the one that is passed in?

Comment: `var = []` is replacing the `var` that was passed in with a completely new, separate list.

Comment: Python doesn’t have pass by reference; it’s always pass by value (reassigning a parameter never affects the caller). However, all values are references (`a = []; b = a; a.append(1); b`).

Comment: Or you could call `var.clear()`.

Comment: @NathanPierson why?

Comment: so it would be passes the list by reference?

Comment: `var = []` is an assignment. It replaces what's in `var` with `[]` but it doesn't do anything to what was previously in `var`. `var.clear()` would mutate `var` in place, and if `var` is still pointing to the list you passed in, it'll clear the contents of the list.

Comment: Python *uses neither call by value nor call by reference*. It uses "call by object sharing". See [this good article about the differences](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) and why it is neither call by value nor call by reference, but a distinct evaluation strategy (which is actually quite common in modern languages, e.g. Javascript, Ruby, Java (for reference types) etc)

Comment: @alwaysdiscrete **it is neither**. Python doesn't use call by value or call by reference as its evaluation strategy. There are more than two evaluation strategies. You are assuming a false dichotemy

Answer (score 2):

Neither.

`var = []` makes `var` to be a new local variable inside `foo`. It has nothing to do with the list outside of `foo`

Comment: its one of them

Comment: To put it more precisely, it assigns a *new list* to the local variable (that corresponds to the parameter)